# Mostrar Calificaciones de acuerdo a materia PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Buenos días Comunidad.
Tengo este reporte de notas del alumno por materia [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero he tratado de hacerlo que las notas vayan en forma horizontal de acuerdo a la materia y no en vertical de acuerdo a la imagen.
No he podido solucionar esta inquietud.

El codigo que ocupo es

```
class Consultar_Materias extends Conexion{
    private $consulta;
    private $fetch;

    function __construct($codigo){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->consulta = $this->conexion_db->query("SELECT * FROM materia WHERE id='$codigo'");
        $this->fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($this->consulta);
    }

    function consultar($campo){
        return $this->fetch[$campo];
    }
}
```

este codigo es el de la pagina:

```
if(!empty($_GET['cod']) and !empty($_GET['periodo'])){
    $id_periodo=$_GET['periodo'];
    $id_alumno=$_GET['cod'];
    $oPeriodo=new Consultar_Periodo($id_periodo);
    $oAlumno=new Consultar_Alumno($id_alumno);  
    $nombre_alumno=$oAlumno->consultar('nombre');

    $oGrado= new Consultar_Grado($oAlumno->consultar('grado'));
    $oSalon= new Consultar_Salon($oAlumno->consultar('salon'));

    $nombre_salon=$oSalon->consultar('nombre');
    $nombre_grado=$oGrado->consultar('nombre');

    $oEmpresa= new Consultar_Empresa('1');

    $dir='Direccion: '.$oEmpresa->consultar('direccion').'<br>'.$oEmpresa->consultar('pais').' - Viña del Mar';

    $regresar=$oAlumno->consultar('salon');#5
}else{
    header('Location:error.php');
}
</table>
      <br />
      <table width="90%" rules="all" border="1" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
      <tr>
        <td>
            <center><strong>Nombre del Alumno</strong><br /><?php echo $nombre_alumno; ?></center>
        </td>
        <td width="25%"><center><strong>Curso</strong><br /><?php echo $nombre_grado; ?></center></td>
        <td width="25%"><center><strong>Sala<br /></strong><?php echo $nombre_salon; ?></center></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><br /><center><strong>Informe del Periodo <?php echo $oPeriodo->consultar('nombre'); ?> Semestre</strong></center></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      <bR />
      <table width="90%" rules="all" border="1" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
      <tr>
        <td width="50%"><strong><center>Materia</center></strong></td>
        <td width="50%"><strong><center>Calificación</center></strong></td>
      </tr>
      <?php 
        $pa=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM notas WHERE alumno='$id_alumno' and periodo='$id_periodo' ORDER BY materia");             
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($pa)){
            $oMateria=new Consultar_Materias($row['materia']);
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td><center><?php echo $oMateria->consultar('nombre'); ?></center></td>
        <td><center><?php echo $row['valor']; ?></center></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

Como puedo poner cada calificacion en horizontal de acuerdo a cada materia

Matematicas | 40 | 50 | 60 | 70 |

Lenguaje    | 55 | 60 | 60 |

Gracias

Comment: Pero no entiendo cuantas columnas quieres que tenga la tabla?, porque no puede ser que para una materia hayan 4 columnas y para la otra 3, en la misma tabla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
</table>
  <br />
  <table width="90%" rules="all" border="1" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
  <tr>
    <td>
        <center><strong>Nombre del Alumno</strong><br /><?php echo $nombre_alumno; ?></center>
    </td>
    <td width="25%"><center><strong>Curso</strong><br /><?php echo $nombre_grado; ?></center></td>
    <td width="25%"><center><strong>Sala<br /></strong><?php echo $nombre_salon; ?></center></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><br /><center><strong>Informe del Periodo <?php echo $oPeriodo->consultar('nombre'); ?> Semestre</strong></center></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <bR />
  <table width="90%" rules="all" border="1" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%"><strong><center>Materia</center></strong></td>
    <td width="50%"><strong><center>Calificación</center></strong></td>
  </tr>
  <?php 


  // creo un contador que nos servirá para más adelante
  $cont = 0;
    $pa=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM notas WHERE alumno='$id_alumno' and periodo='$id_periodo' ORDER BY materia");             
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($pa)){

        // TE MOSTARÁ EL NOMBRE DE LA MATERIA UNA SOLA VEZ PUESTO QUE CONTADOR LO HEMOS INICIADO A 0
        if($cont === 0){
            $materia = $row['materia']
            echo '<td>' . $materia;
            $cont++;
        }

        // TE MUESTRA LAS NOTAS PARA ESA MATERIA
        echo  $row['valor'] . ' | ';

        //aquí comparamos si la materia sigue siendo la misma o no
        //si es distinta la variable `$materia` cambiará por la siguiente materia y en el primer 'if' nos la mostará
        if($materia !== $row['materia']){
            //cerramos el <td> que hemos abierto al mostrar la materia
            echo '</td>';

            //ahora $materia almacena el nombre de la siguiente materia
            $materia = $row['materia']; 

            //contador a 0 para volver a mostrar el nombre de la nueva materia
            $cont = 0;
        }


  ?>
  <!-- ponemos este </td> aquí ya que cuando se termine el 'while' no entrará en el segundo 'if' i así queda cerrado -->
  </td> 

  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Prueba a ver si te funciona, si el código tiene algún error de sintaxis o te salta algún error al ejecutarlo hazlo saber, aún así este método tendría que mostrarte la información como tu quieres

Comment: si pero para mostrar por cada nota recorriendo la tabla notas y con php

Comment: Gracias me ayudo a guiarme!!

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido de ayuda! Un saludo amigo :D