# Realizar informe POR departamento

Tags: php, mysql

Espero me puedan ayudar en algo.

Tengo el siguiente código que realiza un informe **por** departamentos:

```
<?php $departamento = ""; foreach($salidas AS $rowS): ?>
    <?php if ($departamento != $rowS['nombreDepartamento']): $departamento = $rowS['nombreDepartamento'];?>
        <h4>DEPARTAMENTO: <?=$departamento?></h4>
        <table style="width: 100%;" border="1" cellpadding="3">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Departamento</th>
                    <th>Doc</th>
                    <th>Numero</th>
                    <th>Orden</th>
                    <th>Subtotal</th>
                    <th>Descuento</th>
                    <th>Itbis</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    <?php endif; ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$rowS['fecha']?></td>
                    <td><?=$rowS['nombreDepartamento']?></td>
                    <td><?=$rowS['documento']?></td>
                    <td><?=$rowS['numero']?></td>
                    <td><?=$rowS['orden']?></td>
                    <td><?=$rowS['bruto']?></td>
                    <td><?=$rowS['tdesc']?></td>
                    <td><?=$rowS['itbis']?></td>
                    <td><?=$rowS['neto']?></td>
                </tr>

    <?php if ($departamento != $rowS['nombreDepartamento']): ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <hr>
    <?php endif; ?> 
<?php  endforeach; ?>
```

Pero a la hora de mostrarlo los departamentos salen un poco "descuadrados" como se puede apreciar en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber que parte del código podría arreglar para que esto se solucione. Espero su ayuda y gracias por adelantado.

**NOTA:** Me guié de esta respuesta para hacer el código [Link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75392/mostrar-calificaciones-de-acuerdo-a-materia-php-mysql/75402#75402)

Comment: Puedes usar css para que todas las celdas tengan el mismo tamaño  y no varien por tabla

Comment: Osea me refiero al encabezado que dice "DEPARTAMENTO: TODOS", si te fijas el detalle del departamento "TODOS" esta debajo de la cabecera "DEPARTAMENTO: ADMINISTRATIVO", cuando en realidad debería ir debajo del departamento "TODOS"

Comment: Parece que te coge *TODOS* como si fuera un departamento mas, en vez de un cojunto

Comment: Es un departamento mas, el problema es que su detalle _salta_ hacia el siguiente departamento.

Comment: Si lo que deseas es que al capturar el departamento *TODOS* y que en vez de salir inmediatamente debajo *ADMINISTRATIVO* debes realizar un `if` especial para *TODOS* y que dentro de el te coja el resto de departamentos

Comment: No se si te haz fijado que el problema no es solo con el departamento "TODO" si no que también los otros lo tienen. Mira por ejemplo el encabezado que dice: "DEPARTAMENTO: MAYORDOMIA", si te fijas puedes ver que ese departamento tiene el detalle que le debería corresponder al departamento de BIBLIOTECA. NOTA: El sistema toma a "TODOS" como un departamento mas, si hago otra consulta puede ser que el departamento "TODOS" no este, pero siga estando "salto de detalle" (Que un detalle este en otro departamento que no le corresponde).

Comment: No me había fijado, me huele que `<?php if ($departamento != $rowS['nombreDepartamento']): $departamento = $rowS['nombreDepartamento'];?>` tiene algo que ver, también comprueba la SQL si lo está haciendo bien

Comment: Supongo que el problema esta en esa lógica, ya que el SQL lo esta trayendo correctamente.

Comment: Fíjate si traducimos la condición a: `TODOS no es igual a TODOS : TODOS es igual a TODOS`

Comment: Esto es un problema llamado cortes de control. No estas cortando donde corresponde cada tabla, y por eso te sale descuadrado y con titulos desordenados. Es muy probable que el html resultante este mal y por eso te lo muestra mal. El cierre de la tabla no puede estar nunca en la misma iteracion que la apertura ;)

Comment: @gbianchi saque la etiqueta de cierre del `tbody` y la de `table` pero aun persiste el error.

Comment: Podrias hacer un fiddle con un [mcve] para que lo probemos? el tema es que si vieras el html resultante, vas a ver que esta mal formado y por eso ves este problema.

Comment: Saludos no solo estan "descuadrados" tambien si te fijas estan mal agrupados..los de Biblioteca estan en Mayordomia...Administrativo en Almacen y asi con todos..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo haría de otra forma, pero bueno utilizando este mismo código y solo cambiando un par de líneas lo puedes hacer de esta forma:

```
<?php 
    $departamento = ""; 
    foreach($salidas AS $rowS): 
?>

<?php       
    if ($departamento != $rowS['nombreDepartamento']): 
        if ($departamento != ""): ?>
            </tbody>
            </table>
                <hr>
<?php
        endif;
        $departamento = $rowS['nombreDepartamento'];
?>

<h4>DEPARTAMENTO: <?=$departamento?></h4>
    <table style="width: 100%;" border="1" cellpadding="3">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Departamento</th>
                <th>Doc</th>
                <th>Numero</th>
                <th>Orden</th>
                <th>Subtotal</th>
                <th>Descuento</th>
                <th>Itbis</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

<?php   
    endif; ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$rowS['fecha']?></td>
                <td><?=$rowS['nombreDepartamento']?></td>
                <td><?=$rowS['documento']?></td>
                <td><?=$rowS['numero']?></td>
                <td><?=$rowS['orden']?></td>
                <td><?=$rowS['bruto']?></td>
                <td><?=$rowS['tdesc']?></td>
                <td><?=$rowS['itbis']?></td>
                <td><?=$rowS['neto']?></td>
            </tr>

<?php  endforeach; ?>
<?php   if ($departamento != ""): ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr>
<?php   endif; ?>
```

Como ves solo cambio el cierre de la tabla de sitio.

Comment: Perfecto! Ya soluciono el problema, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

prueba a poner lo siguiente mediante css:

```
table{width:100%;}
td{width:3%};
```

Esto hace que la tabla ocupe todo el ancho de la "div" donde esté metida, que el ancho de cada columna sea el mínimo posible (yo suelo poner 3% pero puedes poner el porcentaje que quieras)

Te dejo [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) un enlace con información sobre tablas que te será útil

Comment: Eso no es una respuesta, explica de mejor manera tu solucion.  Te invito a que des un [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que sepas como responder.